# ¿Porque mi codigo en php no recibe parametro $_GET?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un formulario html en el cual tengos varios elementos tipo button y cada uno con un evento onclick.
La funcion en onclick hace lo siguiente. Hacer una peticion con ajax y mostrar datos de cierta tabla de una base de datos. Cada boton consulta tablas distintas . En fin, lo que sucede es que con el primer boton que presiono todo ocurre perfectamente. Se recibe el $_GET sin problema. Pero cuando uso los otros botones pareciera que ignoran la parte de la funcion onclick para efectuar la peticion, no responden. Es acaso un problema con los tipos de botones, no tengo idea, mis peticiones estan formuladas correctamente lo se.

Ignorando el SARCASMO de algunos, aqui va el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Javascript**

```
var PeticionAjax01 = new objeto_ajax(); //Definimos un nuevo objetoAjax.

var PeticionAjax02 = new objeto_ajax(); //Definimos un nuevo objetoAjax.


PeticionAjax01.completado = objetoRequestCompletado01; /*Función completado del objetoAjax redefinida. */

PeticionAjax02.completado = objetoRequestCompletado02; 

var nombre_panel=  "div#panel-personal";//PANEL CUYO CONTENIDO SE MODIFICARA SEGUN SE DESEE VER DATOS DE CARACTER PERSONAL
//JUDICIAL, SITUACION PENITENCIARIA, ETC



function objetoRequestCompletado01(estado, estadoTexto,respuestaTexto, respuestaXML){

$('div#panel-resultados').html( respuestaTexto);
//Solo nos interesa la respuesta como texto
}


function objetoRequestCompletado02(estado, estadoTexto,respuestaTexto, respuestaXML){

$(nombre_panel).html(respuestaTexto); 
//Solo nos interesa la respuesta como texto
}





function consulta_general() {

var seleccion= $('input:radio[name=radio-ci]').val();

var valor= $('input:text[name=txtbusqueda]').val();

var ruta= "consu_mdb2.php?cedula="+valor+"&tipo_bus="+seleccion;

PeticionAjax01.tomar(ruta);
}



function consulta_especi(tipo,posicion) { 

nombre_panel= nombre_panel+ posicion;

var ruta= "consu_mdb2.php?panel="+tipo+"&posicion="+posicion;

alert(ruta); 

PeticionAjax02.tomar("testing.php?panel="+tipo);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ajax

```js
function ConstructorXMLHttpRequest()

{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{

return new XMLHttpRequest();


}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{


var versionesObj = new Array(
'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
'Msxml2.XMLHTTP',
'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

for (var i = 0; i < versionesObj.length; i++)
{

try
{

return new ActiveXObject(versionesObj[i]);

}
catch (errorControlado)
{
 //Capturamos el error, ya que podría crearse otro objeto.
}
}
}


throw new Error("No se pudo crear el objeto XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

clase peticion ajax

```js
function objeto_ajax() {

this.objetoRequest= new ConstructorXMLHttpRequest();


this.tomar= function funcionAsincrona(Url) {

var objetoActual= this;

this.objetoRequest.open('GET', Url, true);

this.objetoRequest.onreadystatechange= 

function() {
switch(objetoActual.objetoRequest.readyState)
{

case 1: //Función que se llama cuando se está cargando.
objetoActual.cargando();

break;
case 2: //Función que se llama cuando se a cargado.
objetoActual.cargado();

break;
case 3: //Función que se llama cuando se está en interactivo.
objetoActual.interactivo();

break;
case 4: 
objetoActual.completado(objetoActual.objetoRequest.status,
objetoActual.objetoRequest.statusText,
objetoActual.objetoRequest.responseText,
objetoActual.objetoRequest.responseXML);

break;
}/**fin switch **/
};
this.objetoRequest.send(null);


}/** fin funcion asincrona **/

this.cargando = function objetoRequestCargando() {}

this.cargado = function objetoRequestCargado() {}

this.interactivo = function objetoRequestInteractivo() {}

this.completado=   function objetoRequestCompletado(estado,estadoTexto, respuestaTexto, respuestaXML) {}

}
```

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código que has hecho para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Deberías mostrar los codigos que has hecho hasta ahora, para analizar tus errores, siguiendo las reglas, para que se evite que tu pregunta sea cerrada, ver en: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ] saludos!

Comment: Envía el codigo para poder ofrecerte una ayuda más completa.

Comment: ¿Cómo está estructurada tu clase de objeto_ajax? ¿Por lo que veo estás usando jQuery, pero para ajax parece como si usaras el objeto nativo de JS XMLHttpRequest, porque no usar simplemente las funciones ajax que ya vienen con jQuery? Falta también el código de PHP y especificar cual de los dos archivos deja de recibir el las variables $_GET después del primer clic.

Comment: esta es una parte:

Comment: if( isset($_GET['panel'])){    
$busqueda_gen= FALSE; 
$v_panel= (int) $_GET['panel'];
echo "PANEL".$_GET['panel']. "dice que " .$v_panel; 
$p_panel= $_GET['posicion']; }

else { $busqueda_gen= TRUE;    }

Comment: Hola Sonia. Por favor copia y pega el codigo, no solo las imagenes, asi quien pueda ayudarte puede copiar el codigo de necesitarlo. Tambien por favor, si vas a hacer aclaraciones a tu codigo, hasla sobre la pregunta directamente, no en los comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando llamas la petición ajax en la función `consulta_especi`, a qué dirección quieres pedir los datos? En el código veo dos direcciones: una a un archivo **consum_mdb2.php** y otra a **testing.php**, pero sólo utilizas **testing.php** y no agregaste el código de ese archivo.